# How to set default sorting order for each column in jQuery Tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have an HTML table, tablesorter works fine on it, I am able to set the default sorting and everything else (even my own parser)... BUT: I need some of the columns to be sorted in descending order after the user first clicks on their respective headers.

By default, all the columns are being sorted in ascending order after the first click. I found a way to change this to descending order for ALL the columns. But what I need is to sort some of the columns in ascending order and some other columns in descending order after the user first clicks on them.

Example: Some columns contain strings, so I want to sort them in ascending order. Some columns contain values where bigger values are better - and it would be nice to sort them in descending order after the user first clicks on their headers.

Thank you.

Comment: API has examples for setting column sorting..what part is giving problems or isn't understandable?

Comment: You probably didn't understand my question completely. See the answer by Mottie, that is exactly what I had in mind and I believe it doesn't work with the default tablesorter from http://tablesorter.com/docs/.

Comment: If he didn't understand the question, it is **your** responsibility to be clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original tablesorter (version 2.0.5) doesn't seem to work with this code:

```
$('table').tablesorter({

    // default sortInitialOrder setting 
    sortInitialOrder: "asc", 

    // pass the headers argument and passing a object 
    headers: {
        2: { sortInitialOrder: 'desc' },
        3: { sortInitialOrder: 'desc' },
        4: { sortInitialOrder: 'desc' }
    }

});
```

But in my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/), you can use the above code to set the initial sort order for each column - see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/35/).

There is also an option named `sortRestart` which resets the sort order when when the column was previously unsorted - see [this demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-option-sortreset-sortrestart.html).

Comment: Great, thank you, this is exactly what I meant. With your tablesorter it works.

Comment: After just a few minutes I already love your tablesorter. Obviously sortRestart is a great thing as well and I love your styles with arrows written directly in CSS instead of being image files. Kudos and thank you again.

Comment: Oh man, excellent work! I'm so happy you posted this. Why on earth isn't there any reference to the fork on http://tablesorter.com/ ???

Comment: @neokio: I've notified the author about my fork, and he actually responded postively, but didn't follow up afterwards.

Comment: It's more than a year since the solution was posted. Were fork changes  already put into the main tree?

Comment: @Budda I'm sad to say that my fork is still separate from the original, and now the [original version of tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter) is hosted on github.